# string concatenation using streams returns junk

Tags: c++, stream, buffer, iostream, cstring

I probably should start stating that I'm pretty new with C++, and, since I come from a higher level language, I may be missing some technical issues that I can't identify.

I have the following method:

```
const char * Point::toString() const {
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << "[" << x << ", " << y << "]"; //[3, 5] for example
    return stream.str().c_str();
}
```

I'm then calling it like this:

```
Point p1 (3, 5);
std::cout << p1.toString() << std::endl;
```

However, this prints some junk.

What am I doing wrong? Also, is my `toString()` method really efficient? Am I leaking memory by allocating a new `char *` and never freeing it?

Comment: Use `std::string Point::toString() const {`, that should work better for you. As soon the functions scope is left, the pointer invalidates.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Wow, that solved the issue! I think I understand now what was happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The char pointer returned by `string::c_str()` is only valid for the lifetime of the string (and only when it is not modified).

But `stream.str()` returns a **temporary** string object, which you need to store somewhere. Otherwise it will be **destroyed** after that exact statement you call that function.

But even if you write

```
string result = stream.str();
return result.c_str();
```

then you destroy the string object inside of the function, **invalidating** the char pointer returned by `c_str()` and resulting in undefined behavior as soon as it is used (dereferenced).

In the end, the best is to just return a string:

```
return stream.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do return `strdup (stream.str().c_str())`, but you should manage this memory by yourself.